# How to implement search in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rails-api

I have frontend AngularJS application that connects to backend API.

I'd like to implement search engine in my SPA so that I can specify

- `offset` - the number of elements displayed on each page
- `page` - number of current page
- `count` - total elements

I also want to sort the results by specified attribute and filter them out as well.

What are the patterns to implement such search? What should be done on backend and what on frontend? How should API look like?

I have a lot of issues with that - what if user requested for 5th page with offset 10, and then change offset to 20, which page should be displayed then? When to fetch additional data? What if I set offset to 15 and then filter out some results, what will give me only 5 elements? Should I fetch missing by current filter?

Can you provide some behaviors of that mechanisms?

Comment: you can achieve using datatable modules like ng-grid or ng-table?

Comment: Asking such questions you need specify ~number of items, ~data total size and number of sortable attributes.